# How to install the Windows 10 Preview to another Partition

Tags: windows-8.1, terminal, windows-10-preview, easybcd, grub4dos

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop but I want to use the Windows 10 on another partition so I don't screw up my files on Windows 8.1. I tried EasyBCD but when I booted to it, it took me to a terminal with the words "GRUB4DOS" on it. How can I use Windows 10 on another partition?

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple. Just burn the ISO to a DVD or bootable USB stick and boot to that device.
When you'r in the Windows Setup you can choose the partition. You don't have to use an sepparate bootmanager, because from windows 8 it's build-in.

Comment: How will I burn it?

Comment: Yes I just downloaded it. I had it before but the VM was pretty slow...

Comment: Ok, I did exactly the same as you ;) Go to the ISO, then right click and "Burn disk image". Make sure you have an empty disk in your computer.

Comment: Ill use an SD Card.

Comment: I don't know if you can boot to a SD Card...

Comment: I have. I booted with Ubuntu 14.04 and Kali Linux 1.0.9a.

Comment: Ah i see. Follow this instructions: http://www.howtogeek.com/191054/how-to-create-bootable-usb-drives-and-sd-cards-for-every-operating-system/

Comment: I saw that. It was helpful.

Comment: Surely if you've done Ubuntu off an SD, this should all be pretty self explanatory?